# Correlation between spins using delta function in Potts model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lattice-model, spin-models

In reading about the [Potts model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model), I found this correlation:
$$\langle s_{i}s_{j} \rangle = \frac{q}{q-1}\frac{1}{N_{p}} \sum_{s_{i},s_{j}} (\delta(s_{i} - s_{j})-\frac{1}{q})$$
with the following text:

> In a completely uncorrelated system, the probability of two spins having the same value is $\frac{1}{q},$ and the correlation will be zero, and in a completely correlated system the expectation of delta function will be 1, and the value in the sum will evaluate to $N\frac{q-1}{q}$, giving the correlation a value of 1.

It's clear for me that correlation is $1$ in a completely correlated system. But I can't understand how is that Delta function is taking the value $\frac{1}{q}$ when the system is uncorrelated.

How does this equation works for a completely uncorrelated system?